# Submit Select2 dropdown without pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

When doing select2 form it submits fine if I press enter but if I press tab to move to the next field and lose my input. I tried using some other select2: events to capture the input but it seems as soon as you lose focus on the field the information is gone. Any way to capture that input on the lose:focus attribute or other event?

Comment: Does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605379/1307183

Comment: it looks like it should, but when implemented the page freezes and has a maximum call stack error. So I may be missing another piece still

Comment: If that's the case then I would post the code you are trying that is causing the issue - perhaps there is an infinite loop somewhere where your events and recursively calling themselves